# Is there a way to open large files in emacs without rendering the session unresponsive for several minutes?

Tags: emacs

In my workflow I'm frequently opening files ranging from 50MB to several hundred MB from AFS volumes located over a wide geographical area. Whenever I open such a file emacs is unresponsive for several minutes. I understand why the file would take this time to load, but is there any way to open the file in the background while leaving the rest of the session responsive?

Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

So it's not about emacs being slow, but the network is slow. How about copying the remote file to a local file and when the transfer is finished then opening a local file with emacs? If the file is edited then it can be copied back remotely from the local file. It could even be automated with rsync or some other method.

Comment: Possibly the detail concerning the AFS shares is a bit of a red herring, as you could obtain similar behavior with a several hundred MB gzipped file stored locally. I agree that in the case I just described gunzipping the file before attempting to open it with emacs would leave the session responsive for the majority of the operation, but it would be very convenient if there is some method by which this could all happen under the covers.

Comment: Emacs is single threaded, so I don't think it's possible, but [you can ask the emacs devs](http://news.gmane.org/gmane.emacs.devel).

Comment: I think you're right, it doesn't look like what I'm hoping for is something natively supported. Thanks for taking the time to answer.